# BOSCH 26A16A ICON Beam Wiper Blades - Driver and Passenger Side

Tags: windshield-wipers

Does [26A & 16A](https://www.amazon.ca/Bosch-ICON-Wiper-Blades-26A16A/dp/B07VH2CXPS/ref=zg_m_bs_g_9164447011_sccl_3/145-4094332-0537907?psc=1) mean that one wiper is 26" and another one is 16"? If so, how would I know if the combo fits my vehicle? I always thought that both wipers had to be of the same length, but that's not the case? Which combination (one long + one short or both of the same length?) is the best? I am sorry if the question sounds "unintelligent". Thank you!

"BOSCH 26A16A ICON Beam Wiper Blades - Driver and Passenger Side"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Bosch, yes, Does this help? https://www.boschautoparts.com/documents/647135/656897/2021%20Bosch%20Wiper%20Blade%20Catalog.pdf

Comment: Thank you all for your assistance and help!

Answer (score 0):

You ask which combination is best in this case, but don't specify what "this case" is.

As a rule of thumb, you check a reputable website/catalog to see wipers recommended for you specific car model, and deduce from that the manufacturer recommended sizes.

Yes, sometimes they will be uneven lengths.

Comment: And if all else fails, you can always measure the wipers that are already on the car.

Comment: @MTA yes, you can measure the current wipers but it's not rare that there's a mismatch between that and manufacturer recommended sizes.

The "wrong" sizes will still work, more or less, just not optimally, or not as the manufacturer intended.